# Easy Install Update stored procedure in sql server express 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, dos, sqlcmd

We have a stored procedure that needs to be updated at a customer site. Basically we will be emailing the changed sp to customer. What is the easiest way a non tech user can install update this sp in sql server express 2005 ? I would ideally like to create some bat file or exe that the user can just double click and the sp gets installed. I know c#,  t-sql and basic dos script commands. OS is win xp. Please do not propose any fancy solutions using powershell since that may not be installed on customer machine. Note this is sql EXPRESS 2005. The sp itself is like any standard sp that has below structure. Worst case I plan to create a word doc with step by step screenshots on how to open sql management studio , open file, execute....

```
use [dbname]
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_name]') 
    AND type     in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_name]  
AS blah blah
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has SQL Server Management Studio, then they also have SQLCMD which is a command line utility for connecting to the database.  You could put your sql script in to a .sql file and then create a .bat file that calls SQLCMD with the appropriate command line switches.

Comment: I will read up on sqlcmd and go with this. Looks easy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build a (C#) application with a `new SqlCommand {type = text}`, containing your update sp, and as long as the connection string info is correct, you should be able to build it, send it to them to run the exe, and then done.

The only difficulty I see is making sure the connection strings are right if you don't already know their environment and aren't working with a technical user.

Good luck!

Comment: If we end up doing this a lot I plan to use your suggestion to create a little sp updater utlity which will read a .sql file , confirm it is a valid sp or fn and do it's magic.. For now I like the sqlcmd approach. thanks

Comment: Glad to give my two cents, it seems like the SQLCMD route is more rapid, even if it requires the user to manipulate more than one file.